# How to render the image with anti-aliasing? C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to draw a smoothed image.

I add a picture in this way:

```cpp
QLabel* label = new QLabel();
label->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/style/images/img.png"));
```

It is displayed, but looks like a "ladder". How can it be smoothed out? Which flag and who to add? I found something similar, but for fonts. How to do it for pictures?

Comment: You could oversize your image and scale down with interpolation. (That would be somehow like anti-aliasing.) -> [`QPixmap::scaled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled) with [`Qt::SmoothTransformation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TransformationMode-enum).

Comment: @Scheff You were right! But not everything. I just added Qt::SmoothTransformation and the picture became much more beautiful, thanks! If you write the answer , I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Why not making a self answer? If it has an [MCVE] I would spend an upvote. ;-)